Openstack Horizon Unshelve "button" not showing on shelved instance
Hi I have an instance that is marked shelved, but the option to un-shelve it doesn't show.


In my experience Horizon only exposes a subset of OpenStack features and for many actions the only way to achieve them is by accessing the API, for example with the OpenStack command line tools.

Yes, understood, but you can shelve/unshelve with Horizon. And when it works it works. So...

Maybe you're logged in with a user that is not allowed to do that. Check horizon policies and the role of your user. If you log in as admin, is the button visible?

No, it's the usual. I seen plenty of people complain of things not working and no errors logs to be found. I'm pretty sure it's in inconsistent state.
